# How to submit base64 string of an uploaded image using only jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here are the jquery codes that i've written

```
$(function(){
  // Prepare the preview for profile picture
      $("#profile_image").change(function(){
          $("#message").empty(); // To remove the previous error message
          var file = this.files[0];
          var imagefile = file.type;
          var match= ["image/jpeg","image/png","image/jpg"];
          if(!((imagefile==match[0]) || (imagefile==match[1]) || (imagefile==match[2])))
          {
            $('#wizardPicturePreview1').attr('src','/images/houses/default.png');
            $("#message").html("<p id='error'>Please Select A valid Image File</p>"+"<h4>Note</h4>"+"<span id='error_message'>Only jpeg, jpg and png Images type allowed</span>");
            return false;
          }
          else
          {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
              $('#wizardPicturePreview1').attr('src', e.target.result).fadeIn('slow');
                //getting the base64 string of the uploaded image
                var imageso =  e.target.result;
                console.log('Encoded image:', imageso);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
          }
      });


  $('form').submit(function() {
    // submit the encoded base64 string of the uploaded image 
    $('.hidden-image-data').val(imageso);

    var formValue = $(this).serialize();
    $('#result-data').text(formValue);

    // Prevent the form from actually submitting
    return true;
  });
});
```

I am getting the encoded image in console with the imageso variable in the change() function but it is nullable In the submit() function, the console tells me that the imageso variable is not declared while it is already declared. The problem is, how to get that base64 string of the uploaded image in the submit funtion using only JQuery without using Ajax?

Comment: i suppose variable imageso are defined outside the submit function so it isn't define when you submit the form.

Comment: That's because `imageso` is not within the scope of the submit handler...

Comment: Declare imageso after the document ready function.

Comment: If i declared the imageso outside, i will not be able to see the base64 string in the change function

Comment: I mean only the declaration part. Assign the value in change function.

Comment: Thx Saravanan N, it works

Comment: Do you really need to send the base64 string? Can't simply append the input[type="file"] inside your `<form>` and let it be uploaded as binary directly? You'd save 34% of data, and asynchronous headaches.

Comment: I know i can do input[type="file"] but that's the way i wanted. Soon, I'm gonna do the cropping and rotation of the uploaded image and it think, i have to send it as base64 string

Comment: Well no, you don't *have* to, you can very well send it as Blob from an AJAX request, which would be the correct way to it by the way. Could you clarify the *why* you explicitly don't want to use the right tool?

Comment: 1) use `URL.createObjectURL(file)` to display the image. 2) use `FormData` to upload your image - don't use base64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx Saravenan N, i've found the answer. Declare imageso after the document ready function

```
$(function(){
  var imageso;
  // Prepare the preview for profile picture
  $("#profile_image").change(function(){
      $("#message").empty(); // To remove the previous error message
      var file = this.files[0];
      var imagefile = file.type;
      var match= ["image/jpeg","image/png","image/jpg"];
      if(!((imagefile==match[0]) || (imagefile==match[1]) || (imagefile==match[2])))
      {
        $('#wizardPicturePreview1').attr('src','/images/houses/default.png');
        $("#message").html("<p id='error'>Please Select A valid Image File</p>"+"<h4>Note</h4>"+"<span id='error_message'>Only jpeg, jpg and png Images type allowed</span>");
        return false;
      }
      else
      {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
          $('#wizardPicturePreview1').attr('src', e.target.result).fadeIn('slow');
            //getting the base64 string of the uploaded image
            imageso =  e.target.result;
            console.log('Encoded image:', imageso);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
      }
  });


$('form').submit(function() {
  // submit the encoded base64 string of the uploaded image 
  $('.hidden-image-data').val(imageso);

  var formValue = $(this).serialize();
  $('#result-data').text(formValue);

  // Prevent the form from actually submitting
  return true;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`imageso` is outside the scope of the submit handler, you won't be able to access the variable as a result.

You will have to bring `imageso` into the submit scope. 
I'd recommend to try and store it in the `sessionStorage`:

```
$(function(){
  // Prepare the preview for profile picture
      $("#profile_image").change(function(){
          $("#message").empty(); // To remove the previous error message
          var file = this.files[0];
          var imagefile = file.type;
          var match= ["image/jpeg","image/png","image/jpg"];
          if(!((imagefile==match[0]) || (imagefile==match[1]) || (imagefile==match[2])))
          {
            $('#wizardPicturePreview1').attr('src','/images/houses/default.png');
            $("#message").html("<p id='error'>Please Select A valid Image File</p>"+"<h4>Note</h4>"+"<span id='error_message'>Only jpeg, jpg and png Images type allowed</span>");
            return false;
          }
          else
          {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
              $('#wizardPicturePreview1').attr('src', e.target.result).fadeIn('slow');
                //getting the base64 string of the uploaded image
                var imageso =  e.target.result;
                sessionStorage.setItem("imageso", imageso);
                console.log('Encoded image:', imageso);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
          }
      });


  $('form').submit(function() {
    // submit the encoded base64 string of the uploaded image 
    $('.hidden-image-data').val(sessionStorage.getItem("imageso"));

    var formValue = $(this).serialize();
    $('#result-data').text(formValue);

    // Prevent the form from actually submitting
    return true;
  });
```

Comment: SessionStorage doesn't work, I've declared imageso after the document ready function and it works.